# why white screen display in-between the slide of content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I have three tab having three contend .I am using slide transition .I am using JQM 1.4.2.My problem is that when I move one tab to another it show white screen .How I will remove that screen using slide transition .here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fRb9L/2/
how to remove that white screen

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div >
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#fragment-1" class="tabBtn" data-transition="slide">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#fragment-2" class="tabBtn" data-transition="slide">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#fragment-3" class="tabBtn" data-transition="slide">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="fragment-1" class="tabContent" data-tabid="0">
        <p>This is the content of the tab 'One', with the id fragment-1.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="fragment-2" class="tabContent" data-tabid="1">
        <p>This is the content of the tab 'Two', with the id fragment-2.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="fragment-3" class="tabContent" data-tabid="2">
        <p>This is the content of the tab 'Three', with the id fragment-3.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is there any update ..? how to show contend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a carousel/slider plugin. For this example I am using the

> **[OWL Carousel Plugin](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)**.

After including the owl crousel js and css in your page, the markup would be:

```
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="tabBtn" data-tabid="0">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tabBtn" data-tabid="1">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tabBtn" data-tabid="2">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div id="fragment-1" class="item">
        <p>This is the content of the tab 'One', with the id fragment-1.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="fragment-2" class="item">
        <p>This is the content of the tab 'Two', with the id fragment-2.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="fragment-3" class="item">
        <p>This is the content of the tab 'Three', with the id fragment-3.</p>
      </div>            
    </div>
</div>

#owl-demo {
    position: relative;
}
#owl-demo .item {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Then the script to setup the carousel is

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  navigation : false, // hide next and prev buttons
  pagination : false, //hide pagination dots
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem:true
});
```

Finally handle the tab button click events to navigate directly to a slide:

```
$(".tabBtn").on("click", function(){
    var tabid = $(this).data("tabid");
    var owl = $("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel');
    owl.goTo(tabid);
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o9foej5L/)**

Comment: thanks great solution but one problem at first time tab don't have active class and when user slide right and left it don't show active class

Comment: can you suggest to add active class when user slide right and left

Comment: thanks for answer ..!! but if you see it is not properly sliding mean when you slide left and right it stop in between .I am using chrome .it chrome behaviour